# Activity causes?(java.lang.nullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I wonder whether it is the Activity declaration in the source code down there cause the ImageView cannot find the R.id.productImgDisplay and this class is only the supporting class and the image is in productsListFragment class

```
package com.example.mobile_e_commerce.dummy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.mobile_e_commerce.ProductsListFragment;
import com.example.mobile_e_commerce.R;

/**
 * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class ProductInfo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    private static final ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.mobile_e_commerce.webserviceurl");

    private final static String NAMESPACE = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
    private  final static String SoapURL = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
    private final static String SOAP_ACTION = rb.getString("SoapAction");
    private final static String METHOD_NAME = rb.getString("OperationName");
    private final String SOAP_ACTION2 = rb.getString("SoapAction2");
    private final String METHOD_NAME2 = rb.getString("OperationName2");
    private final String SOAP_ACTION3 = rb.getString("SoapAction3");
    private final String METHOD_NAME3 = rb.getString("OperationName3");
    private final String SOAP_ACTION4 = rb.getString("SoapAction4");
    private final String METHOD_NAME4 = rb.getString("OperationName4");
    private final String SOAP_ACTION5 = rb.getString("SoapAction5");
    private final static String METHOD_NAME5 = rb.getString("OperationName5");
    private final static String SOAP_ACTION6 = rb.getString("SoapAction6");//image location
    private final static String METHOD_NAME6 = rb.getString("OperationName6");//image location
    private final static String SOAP_ACTION7 = rb.getString("SoapAction7");
    private final static String METHOD_NAME7 = rb.getString("OperationName7");
```

It didn't inheritate the activity class so i initialize myself so that i can i use the findViewById.

```
    Activity activity = new Activity();

    public static List<ProductItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<ProductItem>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */


    //  private File file = new File(Integer.toString(R.drawable.search));

         private String[] valuePass = new String[100];
         private String imgData= "";
         private String imgLoc;
         private String Product = "Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom";
         private int i;
         PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        // ImageView imageView = (ImageView)Activity.findViewById(R.id.productImgDisplay);

         private int n =0;
         PropertyInfo getInfo = new PropertyInfo();
         //  private int number = 0;



     @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         try
            {
            //get the no of the product
                Object response2 = null;
                    SoapObject request2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME5);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                            envelope2.dotNet = true;

                envelope2.setOutputSoapObject(request2);

                HttpTransportSE httpTransport2 = new HttpTransportSE(SoapURL);

                httpTransport2.call(SOAP_ACTION5, envelope2);
                response2 = envelope2.getResponse();

                i = Integer.parseInt(response2.toString());


                //get the imageData of the product
                pi.setName("name");
                pi.setValue("Samsung Galaxy S III 16GB");
                pi.setType(String.class);
                Object response3 = null;
                    SoapObject request3 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME7);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope3 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    request3.addProperty(pi);   
                    envelope3.dotNet = true;

                envelope3.setOutputSoapObject(request3);

                HttpTransportSE httpTransport3 = new HttpTransportSE(SoapURL);
                httpTransport3.call(SOAP_ACTION7, envelope3);
                response3 = envelope3.getResponse();
                imgData = response3.toString();
                //Log.e("Image Data: ", imgData);
```

After i add the value to webservices and get the result back,i pass it to the image loader method down there .

```
ImageLoader(imgData);
try {
    //get the name of the product
    Object response = null;

    while(n < i) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        request.addProperty("number", n);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SoapURL);
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();

        //imageurl equal to byte type image data,will add to WS later

        valuePass[n] = response.toString();
        addItem(new ProductItem(Integer.toString(i), valuePass[n]));

        n++;
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Apps Error", exception.toString());
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Apps Error", exception.toString());
}
return null;

}

public void setExecution(ProductsListFragment exec)//to initialize the variable using class
{
    this.execute();
}

public static Map<String, ProductItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, ProductItem>();
/*static {
//  // Add 3 sample items.
    addItem(new ProductItem("1", "Item 1"));
    addItem(new ProductItem("2", "Item 2"));
    addItem(new ProductItem("3", "Item 3"));
}*/

private static void addItem(ProductItem item) {
    //Log.e("Item added second", item.toString());
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

public Byte imageToByte()//generate byte type image
{
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\SYNLAPUSR004\\workspace\\Mobile_E-Commerce\\res\\drawable-hdpi\\s3.jpg");
    Byte[] c = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        while ((fis.read()) != -1) {
            c[i] = (byte) fis.read();
            i++;
            fis.close();
            return c[i];
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem occur in the line where i use activity.findViewbyID and it return me the java.lang.nullPointerException, it just seems like i pass the value to a non declare pointer or something.This method should set the R.id.productImgDisplay to the picture i get from web services.

```
    public void ImageLoader(String imageData)
    {
        Bitmap bm;
    //  byte[] bitmapdata = null;
        ImageView P_Image = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.productImgDisplay);
        // activity = ProductsListFragment;

        /*
            byte[] fileBytes = imageData.getBytes();
        // Log.e("Image Data", (imageData.getBytes()).toString());
        // Log.e("Image Location", imageLoc);
           File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "s3.jpg");
         //File file = new File(,"s3.jpg");
           Log.e("File Directory", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
         try
         { 
                         // file.createNewFile();
                          OutputStream targetFile=  
                          new FileOutputStream(
                              file);
                          targetFile.write(fileBytes);
                          targetFile.close();


         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }*/
    //  bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData.getBytes(), 0, imageData.getBytes().length);
        Log.e("Image Ori Data: ", bm.toString());
        P_Image.setImageBitmap(bm);
        P_Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class ProductItem {//Instantiation of variable
        public String id;
        public String content;

        public ProductItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat :

```
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at com.example.mobile_e_commerce.dummy.ProductInfo.ImageLoader(ProductInfo.java:224)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at com.example.mobile_e_commerce.dummy.ProductInfo.doInBackground(ProductInfo.java:119)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at com.example.mobile_e_commerce.dummy.ProductInfo.doInBackground(ProductInfo.java:1)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-14 10:58:15.471: W/System.err(5939):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-14 10:58:15.471: E/Apps Error(5939): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: `Activity activity = new Activity();`  itself is wrong. You can pass the view initialized in activity to the constructor of asynctask.

Comment: actually i execute this method in ProductListFragment class but the image get from web service locate in productInfo so may i know how to use the findviewbyid in a class without activity class???

Comment: even if you fix NPE you are still updating views from doInbackground. so will end in crash again

Comment: which means i should get the image data from my res folder but not from web services???

Comment: you can get iamge from from server but you need to update ui on the ui thread

Comment: can u gv me an example???im quite new to android...

Comment: and how to solve the activity problem???

Comment: initialize the image view in Activity and then pass the imageview to the constructor of asynctask. get image in doinbackground in on posteecute update the ui ie set image to imageview